# C++ exception not caught at iOS in some cases

Tags: c++, ios, boost

I have a iOS static Framework written in C++, the following piece of code doing some operation by using boost mmaped_file.

When open failed, boost would throw exception out. It works well on my test phone and most user's phone.

```
try {
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file mmaped_file = createMmapFile();
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_params params = createParams();

    mmaped_file.open(params)
    // doing other operation 
} catch (const std::exception &e) {
    // write log for exception
    log("exception %s", e.what());
}
```

However, in some user's phone, it will produce a crash like below. It looks like when handling the C++ exception, something goes wrong. And it fallback into a default exception handler which terminate the application.

**Does anyone has any clues which reason may cause this and how to prevent it?**

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib   0x1a2d77104 __pthread_kill + 8
1    libsystem_c.dylib        0x1a2cced78 abort + 140
2    libc++abi.dylib          0x1a2398f78 __cxa_bad_cast
3    libc++abi.dylib          0x1a2399108 default_terminate_handler() + 280
4    libobjc.A.dylib          0x1a23b1e58 _objc_terminate() + 140
5    libc++abi.dylib          0x1a23a50fc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
6    libc++abi.dylib          0x1a23a4a40 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*)
7    Myapplication            0x103d10fd8 void boost::throw_exception<std::__1::ios_base::failure>(std::__1::ios_base::failure const&) + 64
8    Myapplication            0x103d112e4 boost::iostreams::detail::mapped_file_impl::open_file(boost::iostreams::basic_mapped_file_params<boost::iostreams::detail::path>) + 440
9    Myapplication            0x103d10e84 boost::iostreams::detail::mapped_file_impl::open(boost::iostreams::basic_mapped_file_params<boost::iostreams::detail::path>) + 116
10   Myapplication            0x103d11a90 boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::open_impl(boost::iostreams::basic_mapped_file_params<boost::iostreams::detail::path> const&) + 92
11   Myapplication            0x1042c3430 void boost::iostreams::mapped_file::open<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(boost::iostreams::basic_mapped_file_params<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > const&) + 76
```

The boost throw exception like this `boost::iostreams::detail::throw_system_failure(msg)`, it throws `std::ios::failure` which is derived from `std::exception`.

**My Analyze**

1. Most user has low memory less than 100MB, some of them are less than 50MB. I guess it might related to the crash.

Comment: what is `log` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number log is a printf print log to console

Comment: If something throws an exception that is *not* derived from `std::exception` (like `throw 666;`) then your code won't catch it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The boost throws `std::ios::failure` which is derived from std::exception.